# Date vs String manipulation Swift2 Best Practise

Tags: string, swift, swift2, nsdate, nsdateformatter

an API returns me this value in a json file:

```
2016-05-11T00:00:00,2016-05-11T21:22:59
```

Now I need to extract the time of date after the "," in this format hh:mm

So for this example I'd like to have this result "21:22". Because I later need this value as a string I guess the string approach is easier in this case?

What ist the best way to do this? Should I use string manipulation or use as NSDate object?

Sorry I'm quite new to swift mostly did javascript in the past.

Any help is highly appreciated.

BR

nikolay

Comment: Do you always need the date the API provides? Or does it ever have to account for the user's location, if so, I'd rec. creating an NSDate object, you can always make a new formatter to get the time out of it later as a string.

Comment: A good question. I only tested the API in germany so I'm not sure if it changes timezones. But I always want to report based on german time (the service is only available in germany) and if users of the report app are in a different timezone the app should still report based on german timezone. Is this understandable? Sorry not a native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let period = "2016-05-11T00:00:00,2016-05-11T21:22:59"

// split the string into date string
let dateStrings = period.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

// define date parser
let parser = NSDateFormatter()
parser.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

// parse dates
let dates = dateStrings.map { parser.dateFromString($0)! }

// generate a string from the second date using system settings
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .NoStyle
formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
// or formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

let timeString = formatter.stringFromDate(dates[1])

print(timeString)
```

Comment: Thanks Sulthan! Way better than my approach.